# datetime dtypes in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading in a csv file with multiple datetime columns.  I'd need to set the data types upon reading in the file, but datetimes appear to be a problem.  For instance:

```
headers = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
dtypes = ['datetime', 'datetime', 'str', 'float']
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes)
```

When run gives a error:

> TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood

Converting columns after the fact, via pandas.to_datetime() isn't an option I can't know which columns will be datetime objects.  That information can change and comes from whatever informs my dtypes list.

Alternatively, I've tried to load the csv file with numpy.genfromtxt, set the dtypes in that function, and then convert to a pandas.dataframe but it garbles the data.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 427):

## Why it does not work

There is no datetime dtype to be set for read_csv as csv files can only contain strings, integers and floats.

Setting a dtype to datetime will make pandas interpret the datetime as an object, meaning you will end up with a string.

## Pandas way of solving this

The [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function has a keyword argument called `parse_dates`

Using this you can on the fly convert strings, floats or integers into datetimes using the default `date_parser` (`dateutil.parser.parser`)

```
headers = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
dtypes = {'col1': 'str', 'col2': 'str', 'col3': 'str', 'col4': 'float'}
parse_dates = ['col1', 'col2']
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=parse_dates)
```

This will cause pandas to read `col1` and `col2` as strings, which they most likely are ("2016-05-05" etc.) and after having read the string, the date_parser for each column will act upon that string and give back whatever that function returns.

## Defining your own date parsing function:

The [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function **also** has a keyword argument called `date_parser`

Setting this to a lambda function will make that particular function be used for the parsing of the dates.

#### GOTCHA WARNING

You have to give it the function, not the execution of the function, thus this is **Correct**

```
date_parser = pd.datetools.to_datetime
```

This is **incorrect**:

```
date_parser = pd.datetools.to_datetime()
```

#### Pandas 0.22 Update

`pd.datetools.to_datetime` has been relocated to `date_parser = pd.to_datetime`

Thanks @stackoverYC

Comment: This is a slow solution. See this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882573/pandas-slow-date-conversion

Comment: @user1761806 Hey good find! I made a better one though. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46183514/3730397

Comment: On pandas 0.22.0 says `pandas.core.datetools.to_datetime` is deprecated, use `pd.datetools.to_datetime` instead. like this: `date_parser = pd.to_datetime`

Comment: There's also a `converters` parameter where you can specify which columns have which converters.  parse_dates is helpful and handles bad data but is slower due to it testing and inferring each value https://gist.github.com/gjreda/7433f5f70299610d9b6b

Comment: Don't forget to add `skiprows=1` if you already have a header in your file.

Comment: I have all values type of text in database, when I set `dtypes="str"`, even I defined `parse_dates` attribute

Comment: @shmnff sounds like you need to open a new question with a small reproducable piece of code and with a data example

Answer (score 73):

There is a `parse_dates` parameter for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) which allows you to define the names of the columns you want treated as dates or datetimes:

```
date_cols = ['col1', 'col2']
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=headers, parse_dates=date_cols)
```

Comment: I was having error as I was passing single string name of column, now I understand that I needed to pass list for a single value also.

Comment: how do you use dtype to define non-date columns whilst using parse_dates for date columns?

Answer (score 23):

You might try passing actual types instead of strings.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
headers = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'] 
dtypes = [datetime, datetime, str, float] 
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes)
```

But it's going to be really hard to diagnose this without any of your data to tinker with.

And really, you probably want pandas to parse the the dates into TimeStamps, so that might be:

```
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=headers, parse_dates=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

My workaround was to load as its default type, then use pandas.to_datetime() function one line down.

```
df[target_col] = pd.to_datetime(df[target_col])
```

Answer (score 7):

I used the following code and it worked:

```
headers = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
df=pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=headers, parse_dates=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Comment: Add context as to why this worked for you would help other users understand your answer in a better way.

Comment: yes, but did this enforce col3-str and col4=float?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the dtypes=[datetime, ...] option, but

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
headers = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'] 
dtypes = [datetime, datetime, str, float] 
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes)
```

I encountered the following error:

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

The only change I had to make is to replace datetime with datetime.datetime

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
headers = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'] 
dtypes = [datetime.datetime, datetime.datetime, str, float] 
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes)
```

Comment: This will still make the dtype of the resulting dataframe an object, not a pandas.datetime

Comment: Aside from the fact that this doesn't have the desired effect, it also doesn't work: `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`