# Pandas: slow date conversion

Tags: python, optimization, pandas

I'm reading a huge `CSV` with a date field in the format `YYYYMMDD` and I'm using the following lambda to convert it when reading:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filen,
                 index_col=None,
                 header=None,
                 parse_dates=[0],
                 date_parser=lambda t:pd.to_datetime(str(t),
                                            format='%Y%m%d', coerce=True))
```

This function is very slow though.

Any suggestion to improve it?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**Note: As [@ritchie46's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59682653/1978504) states, this solution may be redundant since pandas version 0.25 per the new argument [`cache_dates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) that defaults to `True`**

Try using this function for parsing dates:

```
def lookup(date_pd_series, format=None):
    """
    This is an extremely fast approach to datetime parsing.
    For large data, the same dates are often repeated. Rather than
    re-parse these, we store all unique dates, parse them, and
    use a lookup to convert all dates.
    """
    dates = {date:pd.to_datetime(date, format=format) for date in date_pd_series.unique()}
    return date_pd_series.map(dates)
```

Use it like:

```
df['date-column'] = lookup(df['date-column'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

Benchmarks:

```
$ python date-parse.py
to_datetime: 5799 ms
dateutil:    5162 ms
strptime:    1651 ms
manual:       242 ms
lookup:        32 ms
```

Source: https://github.com/sanand0/benchmarks/tree/master/date-parse

Comment: There's a problem with NaN: `return s.apply(lambda v: dates[v])
KeyError: nan`

Comment: Weird. I couldn't reproduce it. Can we see the series that you are passing to the function ? Also, what is your Pandas version.

Comment: Wow: this is super!  I have 1M row test file.  It takes 1 second to read it (no date parsing) but 1m20s if I turn on parse_dates.  Your lookup() solution adds only 0.4 seconds to the initial 1 sec read_csv().

Comment: @fixxer this is incredible..clever use of apply!  what a great principle..can be applied as a function for any kind of dict look up.

Comment: Actually, lookup2 function that uses .map instead .apply is way faster. Here's the code - https://github.com/sanand0/benchmarks/blob/master/date-parse/date-parse.py

Comment: @fixxxer this is incredibly fast, but I am also getting KeyErro: nan.  Here is a series with a np.nan value.

Comment: The benchmark results above are based on parsing 100,000 identical dates. I haven't run into data like this before. I've re-run the same test using 100,000 random dates and now find that "manual" is much faster than "lookup". Unsurprisingly as I introduce more repeated dates, "lookup" performs better. On my system it surpasses "manual" at roughly 125 repetitions per date.

Comment: I have a csv with ~2.5 M. There is one date column among those which i choose to read. Reading CSV without any specific option, takes ~9s. If I read with parse_dates on that column, it takes 2m20s. With this lookup function (exactly above), it takes (much) longer, about 3m35s. seems that this answer doesnt work for every data, at least not in my case.

Comment: I also supplied the optimal `format=` argument in your `pd.to_datetime` line. Anyway, this piece of code sped it up like crazy. I had a 13 GB csv and each date was repeated about 340,000 times. I was previously including `cache=True` in `pd.to_datetime`, thinking that its performance would be similar, but this is wildly faster.

Comment: I am somewhat surprised this is the accepted answer because without specifying a format for the pandas datetime converter there is *no guarantee this function will convert the dates consistently*. I have personally run into this issue when testing this snippet. The edit to make this correct is simple but a crucial one. I would NOT trust this to run without specifying a datetime format.

Comment: Extremely useful. saved my time.

Answer (score 16):

Great suggestion @EdChum! As @EdChum suggests, using `infer_datetime_format=True` can be **significantly** faster. Below is my example.

I have a file of temperature data from a sensor log, which looks like this:

> ```
> RecNum,Date,LocationID,Unused
> 1,11/7/2013 20:53:01,13.60,"117","1",
> 2,11/7/2013 21:08:01,13.60,"117","1",
> 3,11/7/2013 21:23:01,13.60,"117","1",
> 4,11/7/2013 21:38:01,13.60,"117","1",
> ...
> ```

My code reads the csv and parses the date (`parse_dates=['Date']`).
With `infer_datetime_format=False`, it takes **8min 8sec**:

> ```
> Tue Jan 24 12:18:27 2017 - Loading the Temperature data file.
> Tue Jan 24 12:18:27 2017 - Temperature file is 88.172 MB.
> Tue Jan 24 12:18:27 2017 - Loading into memory. Please be patient.
> Tue Jan 24 12:26:35 2017 - Success: loaded 2,169,903 records.
> ```

With `infer_datetime_format=True`, it takes **13sec**:

> ```
> Tue Jan 24 13:19:58 2017 - Loading the Temperature data file.
> Tue Jan 24 13:19:58 2017 - Temperature file is 88.172 MB.
> Tue Jan 24 13:19:58 2017 - Loading into memory. Please be patient.
> Tue Jan 24 13:20:11 2017 - Success: loaded 2,169,903 records.
> ```

Comment: Omitting `infer_datetime_format` also generates a very long and angry set of warnings telling you to not omit it even if it still runs with no error.

Answer (score 7):

## Unless you're stuck with a very old version of pandas, pre 0.25, this answer is not for you.

The functionality described here has been merged into pandas in version 0.25

### Streamlined date parsing with caching

Reading all data and then converting it will always be slower than converting while reading the CSV. Since you won't need to iterate over all the data twice if you do it right away. You also don't have to store it as strings in memory.

We can define our own date parser that utilizes a cache for the dates it has already seen.

```
import pandas as pd

cache = {}

def cached_date_parser(s):
    if s in cache:
        return cache[s]
    dt = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y%m%d', coerce=True)
    cache[s] = dt
    return dt
    
df = pd.read_csv(filen,
                 index_col=None,
                 header=None,
                 parse_dates=[0],
                 date_parser=cached_date_parser)
```

Has the same advantages as @fixxxer s answer with only parsing each string once, with the extra added bonus of not having to read all the data and THEN parse it. Saving you memory and processing time.

Comment: I got error `to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coerce'`. When I tried to pass the argument `errors='coerce'`, I got `NaT` instead.

Comment: Thank you for shating this, but as @ritchie46 indicated, since pandas 0.25 the caching is automatically done by default through `cache_dates=boolean`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59682653/2906290

Answer (score 6):

Since [pandas version 0.25](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) the function `pandas.read_csv` accepts a `cache_dates=boolean` (which defaults to `True`) keyword argument. So no need to write your own function for caching as done in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

No need to specify a `date_parser`, pandas is able to parse this without any trouble, plus it will be much faster:

```
In [21]:

import io
import pandas as pd
t="""date,val
20120608,12321
20130608,12321
20140308,12321"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0])
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date    3 non-null datetime64[ns]
val     3 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 72.0 bytes
In [22]:

df
Out[22]:
        date    val
0 2012-06-08  12321
1 2013-06-08  12321
2 2014-03-08  12321
```

Comment: isn't inferring going to make things even slower?

Comment: @MarcusMüller don't know unless you try, the docs seem to imply that once it's sniffed the format it may optimise the date parsing rather than guessing each time

Answer (score 3):

Try the standard library:

```
import datetime
parser = lambda t: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(t), "%Y%m%d")
```

However, I don't really know if this is much faster than pandas.

Since your format is so simple, what about

```
def parse(t):
     string_ = str(t)
     return datetime.date(int(string_[:4]), int(string[4:6]), int(string[6:]))
```

**EDIT** you say you need to take care of invalid data.

```
def parse(t):
     string_ = str(t)
     try:
         return datetime.date(int(string_[:4]), int(string[4:6]), int(string[6:]))
     except:
         return default_datetime #you should define that somewhere else
```

All in all, I'm a bit conflicted about the validity of your problem:

- you need to be fast, but still you get your data from a CSV
- you need to be fast, but still need to deal with invalid data

That's kind of contradicting; my personal approach here would be assuming that your "huge" CSV just needs to be brought into a better-performing format once, and you either shouldn't care about speed of that conversion process (because it only happens once) or you should probably bring whatever produces the CSV to give you better data--there's so many formats that don't rely on string parsing.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work well with invalid dates in some rows (I'm not sure how to `coerce` using your method

Comment: you didn't mention that you need to take care of invalid data; that's a bit of an unfair problem

Answer (score 1):

If your datetime has UTC timestamp and you just need part of it. Convert it to a string, slice what you need and then apply the below for much faster access.

```
created_at
2018-01-31 15:15:08 UTC
2018-01-31 15:16:02 UTC
2018-01-31 15:27:10 UTC
2018-02-01 07:05:55 UTC
2018-02-01 08:50:14 UTC

df["date"]=  df["created_at"].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:10])


df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a csv with ~150k rows. After trying almost all the suggestions in this post, I found 25% faster to:

1. read the file row by row using Python3.7 native `csv.reader`
2. convert all 4 numeric columns using `float()` and
3. parse the date column with `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()`

and Behold:

4. finally convert the list to a DataFrame (!)**

It baffles me how can this be faster than native pandas pd.read_csv(...)... can someone explain?