# Pandas Equivalent to SQL YEAR(GETDATE())

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, date, pandas, filter

I'm a Pandas newbie but decent at SQL.  A function I often leverage in SQL is this:

```
YEAR(date_format_data) = (YEAR(GETDATE())-1)
```

This will get me all the data from last year.  Can someone please help me understand how to do the equivalent in Pandas?

Here's some example data:

```
Date     Number
01/01/15 1
01/02/15 2
01/01/15 3
01/01/16 2
01/01/16 1
```

And here's my best guess at the code:

```
df = df[YEAR('Date') == (YEAR(GETDATE()) -1)].agg(['sum'])
```

And this code would return a value of '3'.

Thank you in advance for your help, I'm having a really hard time figuring out what I'm sure is simple.

Me

Comment: You may need to first convert your `Date` column to datetime objects with `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`.

Comment: If you're using `pd.to_datetime` performance might be an issue if the date isn't in a standard format. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882573/pandas-slow-date-conversion) might be useful then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it this way:

```
prev_year = pd.datetime.today().year - 1
df.loc[df['Date'].dt.year == prev_year]
```

PS `.dt.year` accessor will work only if `Date` column is of `datetime` dtype. If it's not the case you may want to convert that column to `datetime` dtype first:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: did you mean '1 year' instead of '1 day' in your example code?

Comment: @SDS, as far as i know `GETDATE()-1` - is (today minus one day) yesterday. Did you mean something different?

Comment: Sorry MaxU, you are right - I want to go back one year, not one day.  My error, will update code above.

Comment: @SDS, i've updated my answer correspondingly... But now i'm not sure that it's what you need. Are you sure you want to compare only the "year" part?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to compare year over year sales transactions. I want the reports to update dynamically rather than update hard coded years.  This code example will work for months and weeks so I should be good.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For pandas, first convert your date column to timestamp by [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

(`pd.to_datetime` has a format parameter to specify your input date format) Then you have

```
df['Date2'].year
```