# Convert string date time to pandas datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, datetime

I am new to Pandas and Python. I want to do some date time operations in my script. 
I am getting date time information from a csv file in following format:
 **01APR2017 6:59**

How to convert it into pandas datetime format? Something like: 
**2017-04-01 06:59:00**

Comment: There is a duplicate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269399/datetime-dtypes-in-pandas-read-csv) which is helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html) with parameter `format`:

```
s = pd.Series(['01APR2017 6:59','01APR2017 6:59'])

print (s)
0    01APR2017 6:59
1    01APR2017 6:59
dtype: object

print (pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d%b%Y %H:%M'))
0   2017-04-01 06:59:00
1   2017-04-01 06:59:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Another possible solution is use `date_parser` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""date
01APR2017 6:59
01APR2017 6:59"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%Y %H:%M')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[0], date_parser=parser)

print (df)
                 date
0 2017-04-01 06:59:00
1 2017-04-01 06:59:00

print (df.date.dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```

EDIT by comment:

If values cannot be parsed to `datetime`, add parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert to `NaT`:

```
s = pd.Series(['01APR2017 6:59','01APR2017 6:59', 'a'])
print (s)
0    01APR2017 6:59
1    01APR2017 6:59
2                 a
dtype: object

print (pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d%b%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce'))
0   2017-04-01 06:59:00
1   2017-04-01 06:59:00
2                   NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried solution #1 but i am getting following error - ValueError: time data ' 01APR2017 6:59' does not match format '%d%b%y %H:%M'

some of the fields in that colum of csv contains no date and are blank/empty

Comment: Hi Jezrael, It seems the problem is that the dtype of my column is float. How to change it to object type?

Comment: use `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str)`, but if data are like `01APR2017 6:59` it is string, not float.