# ValueError: time data- does not match format - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I know this question has been asked many times and there are many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015711/time-data-does-not-match-format). I followed the previous threads, still not getting my answer. 
When I did this, without `errors= coerce`

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format= "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I get an error:

> ValueError: time data '26-Aug-17 10:11:29' does not match format '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)

As you can see, I think I have the right format. But still it gives error.

When I do with `errors= coerce` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501726/convert-string-date-time-to-pandas-datetime) post,

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format= "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S", `errors= coerce`)
```

This runs fine, but I get `NaT` in my `DATE` column. For example, like this,

```
        Date                    X           DATE    
  0    26-Aug-17 10:11:29    95.617378      NaT
  1    26-Aug-17 11:11:29    93.617378      NaT
  2    26-Aug-17 12:11:29    91.617378      NaT
  3    26-Aug-17 13:11:29    90.000000      NaT
```

I have the format correct and still can not find why am I getting this error. Any thoughts will be helpful.

Comment: @jezrael thanks for suggestion, still getting the same results. No changes!

Comment: `print (df['Date'].tolist()[:10])`  gives `'26-Aug-17 10:11:29', '26-Aug-17 11:11:29', '26-Aug-17 12:11:29',`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need change `Y` to `y`, because `Y` required full year, but `y` only last 2 digits, see http://strftime.org/:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format= "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
print (df)
                 Date          X                DATE
0  26-Aug-17 10:11:29  95.617378 2017-08-26 10:11:29
1  26-Aug-17 11:11:29  93.617378 2017-08-26 11:11:29
2  26-Aug-17 12:11:29  91.617378 2017-08-26 12:11:29
3  26-Aug-17 13:11:29  90.000000 2017-08-26 13:11:29
```