# Pandas validate date format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Is there any nice way to validate that all items in a dataframe's column have a valid date format?

My date format is `11-Aug-2010`.

I saw this generic answer, where:

```
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16870699/1374488

But I assume that's not good (efficient) in my case.

I assume I have to modify the strings to be pandas dates first as mentioned here:
[Convert string date time to pandas datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501726/convert-string-date-time-to-pandas-datetime)

I am new to the Python world, any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

(format borrowed from piRSquared's answer)

```
if pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%b-%Y', errors='coerce').notnull().all():
    # do something
```

This is the LYBL—"Look Before You Leap" approach. This will return `True` assuming all your date strings are valid - meaning they are all converted into actual `pd.Timestamp` objects. Invalid date strings are coerced to `NaT`, which is the datetime equivalent of `NaN`.

Alternatively,

```
try:
    pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%b-%Y', errors='raise')
    # do something
except ValueError:
    pass
```

This is the EAFP—"Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" approach, a `ValueError` is raised when invalid date strings are encountered.

Comment: What if the `'date'` column contains, for example, the value `1`? This would not throw an error in `to_datetime` but probably isn't valid. The best way to get around this would be to specify `format`

Comment: Thanks, I was looking exactly for the LYBL approach! Great!

Comment: What if any format is OK but all needed is to have the same format?

Answer (score 8):

If you know your format, you can use boolean slicing

```
mask = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%d-%b-%Y', errors='coerce').notna()
df.loc[:, mask]
```

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, range(1), ['11-Aug-2010', 'August2010, I think', 1])
df

   11-Aug-2010  August2010, I think  1
0            1                    1  1
```

I can filter with

```
mask = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%d-%b-%Y', errors='coerce').notna()
df.loc[:, mask]

   11-Aug-2010
0            1
```