# Convert weekday name string into datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following date (as an object format) : `Tue 31 Jan` in a pandas Series.

and I try to change it into : `31/01/2019`

Please, how can I achieve this ? I understand more or less that *pandas.Datetime* can convert easily when a string date is clearer (like `6/1/1930 22:00`) but not in my case, when their is a weekday name.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you post the code so we can understand what's going on?

Comment: Generally, you cannot do exactly this reliably, as you have no data about year.

Comment: @prashantrana No, it isn't a duplicate of that.

Comment: @coldspeed sorry my bad , but this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: @prashantrana Please suggest duplicates that are applicable to _pandas only_. I could not find any. Perhaps you can.

Comment: @coldspeed here it is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501726/convert-string-date-time-to-pandas-datetime

Comment: @prashantrana Almost, but that solution doesn't require concatenating the year for it to work....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concat the year and call`pd.to_datetime` with a custom format:

```
s = pd.Series(['Tue 31 Jan', 'Mon 20 Feb',])
pd.to_datetime(s + ' 2019', format='%a %d %b %Y')

0   2019-01-31
1   2019-02-20
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This is fine as long as all your dates follow this format. **If that is not the case, this cannot be solved reliably.**

More information on datetime formats at [strftime.org](http://strftime.org).

---

Another option is using the 3rd party [`dateutil`](https://pypi.org/pypi/python-dateutil/) library:

```
import dateutil
s.apply(dateutil.parser.parse)

0   2018-01-31
1   2018-02-20
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This can be installed with PyPi.

---

Another, slower option (but more flexible) is using the 3rd party [`datefinder`](https://datefinder.readthedocs.io) library to sniff dates from string containing random text (if this is what you need):

```
import datefinder
s.apply(lambda x: next(datefinder.find_dates(x)))

0   2018-01-31
1   2018-02-20
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can install it with PyPi.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much to you and all for your help !

Answer (score 1):

### Convert to a `datetime` object

If you wanted to use the `datetime` module, you could get the year by doing the following:

```
import datetime as dt

d = dt.datetime.strptime('Tue 31 Jan', '%a %d %b').replace(year=dt.datetime.now().year)
```

This is taking the date in your format, but replacing the default year `1900` with the current year in a reliable way.

This is similar to the other answers, but uses the builtin `replace` method as opposed to concatenating a string.

### Output

To get the desired output from your new `datetime` object, you could perform the following:

```
>>> d.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'31/01/2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is two alternate ways to achieve the same result.

**Method 1: Using datetime module**

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Tue 31 Jan', '%a %d %b')

print(datetime_object) # outputs 1900-01-31 00:00:00
```

If you had given an Year parameter like `Tue 31 Jan 2018`, then this code would work.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Tue 31 Jan 2018', '%a %d %b %Y')

print(datetime_object) # outputs 2018-01-31 00:00:00
```

To print the resultant date in a format like this `31/01/2019`. You can use

```
print(datetime_object.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")) # outputs 31/01/2018
```

[Here](http://strftime.org/) are all the possible formatting options available with datetime object.

**Method 2: Using dateutil.parser**

This method automatically fills in the Year parameter with current year.

```
from dateutil import parser

string = "Tue 31 Jan"

date = parser.parse(string)

print(date) # outputs 2018-01-31 00:00:00
```