# Converting a csv file to Datetime

Tags: python, csv, pandas, datetime

I've searched thoroughly for an answer before asking, but all I've been able to find was how to convert one column of my csv file into a datetime object.

My problem is, my file has a separate column for year, month, day, hour, minute, and I've been struggling for a while to convert and combine them.

Any help would be much appreciated.

head of file content:
[viewed in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZZpS.png)

Comment: please provide file content here.. so we can get better idea!

Comment: Have you tried `strptime`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datetime dtypes in pandas read\_csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269399/datetime-dtypes-in-pandas-read-csv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameters `parse_dates` and `date_parser`. See also [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#date-handling):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""year,month,day,hour,minute,a
2017,09,01,10,20,1
2017,10,01,10,20,2
2017,11,01,10,20,3"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H %M')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 parse_dates={'date':['year','month','day','hour','minute']},
                 date_parser=parser)
print (df)
                 date  a
0 2017-09-01 10:20:00  1
1 2017-10-01 10:20:00  2
2 2017-11-01 10:20:00  3
```

Comment: This has been the most helpful! Oh, to actually have a result after typing "print(df)" ... such a relief.

Comment: So output is `file`? Or `dataframe`?

Comment: Dataframe, but I only really needed this format to make my life easier while working with time series forecasting.

Answer (score 2):

I'll write a simple way.

Suppose there is a CSV file like the one below.

```
year,month,day,hour,minute
2017,1,1,23,59
2017,2,1,23,59
2017,3,1,23,59
```

You can parse csv and create a datetime object.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('test.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    next(reader) # skip header
    for row in reader:
        row = [int(r) for r in row]
        print(datetime(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
```

The result is like this.

```
2017-01-01 23:59:00
2017-02-01 23:59:00
2017-03-01 23:59:00
```

thx:)

Comment: @saremisona don't forget to upvote any answer you found useful :)

Comment: I have upvoted everything, it just says it's recorded but not shown because I just joined. I'm sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

this might be a little manual but you could:

1. read each line, split it into your various items (year, month etc) as string.
2. then recompose into a datetime object with datetime.datetime.strptime (which will convert a string with a given format to a datetime).