# Difference between two datetime64[ns] column showing error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

As show in figure I have two dataframe columns of type datetime64[ns]. I need to find difference between them. When I try to do so, I am getting error. If I try to find difference between one element of each column in same data frame, it is giving me time delta.Is there something that I may be missing?

[image]

- I have included date time
- These columns are converted from int64 type column using pd.to_datetime()

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 c =  data['created_at'] - data['launched_at']
>
> /home/adi/.virtualenvs/datascience/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc
>   in wrapper(left, right, name, na_op)
>       694         left, right = _align_method_SERIES(left, right)
>       695 
>   --> 696         converted = _Op.get_op(left, right, name, na_op)
>       697 
>       698         left, right = converted.left, converted.right
>
> /home/adi/.virtualenvs/datascience/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc
>   in get_op(cls, left, right, name, na_op)
>       328             return _Op(left, right, name, na_op)
>       329         else:
>   --> 330             return _TimeOp(left, right, name, na_op)
>       331 
>       332
>
> /home/adi/.virtualenvs/datascience/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc
>   in **init**(self, left, right, name, na_op)
>       341         super(_TimeOp, self).**init**(left, right, name, na_op)
>       342 
>   --> 343         lvalues = self._convert_to_array(left, name=name)
>       344         rvalues = self._convert_to_array(right, name=name, other=lvalues)
>       345
>
> /home/adi/.virtualenvs/datascience/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc
>   in _convert_to_array(self, values, name, other)
>       452             supplied_dtype = values.dtype
>       453         inferred_type = supplied_dtype or lib.infer_dtype(values)
>   --> 454         if (inferred_type in ('datetime64', 'datetime', 'date', 'time') or
>       455                 is_datetimetz(inferred_type)):
>       456             # if we have a other of timedelta, but use pd.NaT here we
>
> TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood

As int64 datatype:

[image]

After conversion to datetime format

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37453925/5811078) might be helpful.

Comment: there he could not convert while reading csv. But in this case, I have columns with required datatype

Comment: can you please show me your dataframe that can help me to solve.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve it by doing an update of pandas to v0.20.2. Actually as I'm using Anaconda I did a  `conda update pandas`  which update things that depends on pandas too (which is to say everything).