# How to load a date column from a CSV straight as datetime[ns] type into a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have a huge CSV file with date columns like this:

```
a,b,c
10-15,2008-10-20,2008-10-21
1996-06-20,1996-06-21,1996-07-25
1998-06-22,1998-06-23,1998-06-23
.
.
.
```

I want to read thsi file  into a Pandas DataFrame while storing the dates straight as `datetime64[ns]` type. So I tried

```
pd.read_csv(fname, dtype={
             'a': np.datetime64,
             'b': np.datetime64,
             'c': np.datetime64 })
```

but the Pandas parser complains.

I want to avoid using the `parse_dates` option or post-processing the DataFrame with `astype`, because the CSV has 50 million rows and each time I load the CSV the conversion takes a long time.

Is there a way to **read the dates straight into `datetime64[ns]`** types?

---

**Update:** As it turns out, reading the CSV with the `parse_dates` option (as suggested in the answers of the [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269399/datetime-dtypes-in-pandas-read-csv)) is performance-wise *not too bad**: On my machine reading the 50 million records takes

- **without conversion** to date objects **2:30 min**
- **with conversion**  to date objects **5:50 min**

Comment: what error are you getting?