# Reduce xtick frequency when stepping with a Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a large dataset using a CSV file I had gathered previously. When I plot the data using `plt.step` every xtick is marked making it unreadable. How do I reduce the number of displayed xticks but keep the same graph?

I have tried using `plt.xticks` with `np.arrange` but I keep getting errors as I am using a Dataframe rather than an array. Additionally the  x values I'm working with is time in the following format (%H:%M:%S).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(thisFile)
plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
plt.step(df.Time, df.HR)

print(df.Time)
```

> Output
>   0       13:40:34
>   1       13:40:44
>   2       14:18:29
>   3       14:19:15
>   4       14:20:58
>   5       14:21:17

```
plt.ylabel('Heart Rate (BPM)')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

Displaying the plot is mostly correct except for the xtick frequency. It appears too often and collides with each other as shown in [my graph output](https://pasteboard.co/IaTQCdS.png).

Ideally I would like for the xticks to display from 12AM to 12PM with a xtick frequency of an hour.

Comment: try: `plt.xticks(your_desired_xticks)`

Comment: You forgot to convert your date strings to actual dates.

Comment: To expand on what @ImportanceOfBeingErnest said: you should specify what *kind of data* pandas can expect from each column, see e.g. in [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37453925/565489) where a `parse_dates=['col1', 'col2']` argument is given to `read_csv()`. To specify the plot range on the x axis, look around here for `plt.xlim( )` and `plt.xticks()`, there are many answers for this already.