# How do I set a Series index to be DatetimeIndex instead of Index?

Tags: python, pandas

I execute the following in the Python REPL:

```
from pandas import read_csv

sales = read_csv('data.csv', header=None, parse_dates=True)
model1 = sales[sales['model'].eq('model1')].groupby('date')['qty').sum()
```

This gives me a series that looks like this:

```
date
2016-09-16    128
2016-09-17     34
2016-09-18      5
2016-09-19     19
2016-09-20     16
             ...
2019-10-03      1
2019-10-07      1
2019-10-11      1
2019-10-12      1
2019-10-14      1
Name: qty, Length: 863, dtype: int64
```

Now I want to group that by weeks and chart it, but when I try to resample it I get the following:

```
model1.resample('W')
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got instance of 'Index'
```

I thought the `parse_dates=True` would take care of that, but it hasn't. How do I tell pandas that the index column is a `DatetimeIndex` or convert it to one?

Comment: You need to pass the date column to parse_dates. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269399/datetime-dtypes-in-pandas-read-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the index by `to_datetime`

```
model1.index=pd.to_datetime(model1.index)
```