# TypeError: data type ' int64' not understood

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following function to load data in my jupyter notebook

```
#function to load data
def load_dataset(x_path, y_path):
    x = pd.read_csv(os.sep.join([DATA_DIR, x_path]),
                    dtype=DTYPES,
                    index_col="ID")
    y = pd.read_csv(os.sep.join([DATA_DIR, y_path]))

    return x, y
```

and the data has the below types defined

```
DTYPES = {
    'ID':'int64',
    'columnA':'str',
    'columnB':'float32',
    'columnC':'float64',
    'columnD':'datetime64[ns]'}
```

The header of the above csv is as below

```
ID          columnA   columnB   columnC         columnD
941215   SALE      15000       56           10/1/2018
```

when I call the method in my notebook

```
from model import load_dataset
X_train, y_train = load_dataset("X_train.zip", "y_train.zip")
```

I get the below error

```
2055 raise TypeError("data type '{}' not understood".format(dtype))
2057     # Any invalid dtype (such as pd.Timestamp) should raise an error.
TypeError: data type ' int64' not understood
```

Comment: could you post the first few lines of the csv file

Comment: Python has no `int64`, it has only `int`. That's a dtype in `numpy`. (`np.int64`).

Comment: You need a capital `I` in `Int64` and make sure there is no leading space. The TypeError looks like you have an extra leading space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need specify [`dtypes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype) in `numpy`:

```
DTYPES = {
    'ID':np.int64,
    'columnA':'str',
    'columnB':np.float32,
    'columnC':np.float64}
```

For datetimes need different approach - parameter [`parse_dates`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37453925/2901002) in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
def load_dataset(x_path, y_path):
    x = pd.read_csv(os.sep.join([DATA_DIR, x_path]),
                    dtype=DTYPES,
                    index_col="ID"
                    parse_dates='columnD')
    y = pd.read_csv(os.sep.join([DATA_DIR, y_path]))

    return x, y
```