# ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (Python)

Tags: python, datetime

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import datetime

my_dates = ['Date']
sorted(my_dates, key=lambda x :datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Getting the error in title. Not sure why. the date format in excel sheet is 1/2/2020 (m/d/yyyy)
Tried many methods off google search and getting same error. Checked excel sheet to see if any dates written wrong but nope.

Python lists the column as object/list

Comment: Hello, can you print(x)? And by the way, `my_dates = ['Date']` means you've set `my_dates` as `a list` containing `1 string "Date"`. Maybe you forgot to add the DF first? `df['Date'].values` ?

Comment: ```print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-188-fc17d851ef81>", line 1, in <module>
    print(x)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined```

Comment: Yeah, that error it's because the x is inside the lambda function. See my edit to my first comment.

Comment: it is unclear how your input data looks - do you mean something like `my_dates = df['Date']`?

Comment: Tried this, same error.

```df = pd.DataFrame(ph, columns = ['E.T.A. DATE'])
my_dates = df
sorted(my_dates, key=lambda x :datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y'))```

Comment: that does not clarify anything... please read the [ask] section and provide a [mre].

Comment: Nevermind got it working: 

```df = pd.DataFrame(ph, columns = ['Date'])
ph['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date''])```

This converted the string to date and time column

Answer (score 1):

`df = pd.DataFrame(ph, columns = ['Date']) ph['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date''])`

Comment: Welcome to SO! From the comments, this looks like a great self-answer. However, it would really benefit from a little explanation to help future readers!

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop you've got `x = 'Date'` which can't be parsed as date, but it will when `my_dates = ['10/28/2020']`

Comment: But it is entire column containing dates, hence using the column header as "Date" which is how it is in excel. I tried changing to say 'ETA Date' and still same error.

Comment: Then you must declare types, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37453925/5274713