# Change separate types with panda methods

Tags: python, dataframe, dtype, pandas

i have this txt and want to change the dtypes of `ID,Foo,Bla,Bar,Timestamp`. For example i want to change ID to `int64`. How can i do that?

```
ID  Foo Bla Bar Timestamp
1   21.07   NaN 2020-15-04
2   22.07   NaN 2005-01-05
3   22.05   Baz 1970-01-01
```

Comment: I think this might provide some help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21269399/2180316

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've read the txt file into a dataframe and the column with ID in it is called "ID" you can cast that column to an int64.

```
import numpy as np
df.astype({'ID': np.int64})
```

[This can help](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) if you want more resources for converting dataframe types.