# How do I import a column as datetime.date?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset in CSV which first column are dates (not datetimes, just dates).

The CSV is like this:

```
date,text
2005-01-01,"FOO-BAR-1"
2005-01-02,"FOO-BAR-2"
```

If I do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv')
```

I get:

```
print(df.dtypes)

date       object
text       object
dtype: object
```

How can I get column date by `datetime.date`?

Comment: Those this help answering your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269399/datetime-dtypes-in-pandas-read-csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', parse_dates=[0])
```

This way the initial column will be of native pandasonic *datetime* type,
which is used in *Pandas* much more often than pythonic *datetime.date*.

It is a more natural approach than conversion of the column in question
after you read the DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. When you say native pandasonic datetime type, is it the same as numpy datetime64? I have followed your advise and it seems that Pandas reports such type for the date column.

Comment: *datetime64* in *Pandas* is roughly the same as in *Numpy*.
An important difference is that in *Numpy* you can set various resolutions (e.g. day or millisecond),
whereas in *Pandas* the only resolution supported is nanosecond (*ns*).
Under the hood, *Pandas* keeps this type as a signed number of nanoseconds since the start of the Unix epoch.
This is why *pandasonic* datetime range is roughly 22.09.1677 – 11.04.2262. If you attempt to save in *Pandas* dates outside this range, an exception occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pd.to_datetime function available in pandas.

For example in a dataset about scores of a cricket match. I can convert the Matchdate column to datatime object by applying **pd.to_datetime** function based on the data time format given in the data. ( Refer https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp to assign commands based on your data time formating )

```
 cricket["MatchDate"]=pd.to_datetime(cricket["MatchDate"], format= "%m-%d-%Y")
```