# PANDAS read_csv: Parse correct Datetime format With "T" string : "2022-01-05T02:24" AND "2022-01-05T02:10:58"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

Parse the correct datetime for multiple columns and different formats in the same column

Hello community,

I have a csv file that I uploaded to jupyter notebook using read_csv from pandas.

I am trying to parse correctly date-times **for multiple columns.**

In the same column, I have two formats of DateTime:

***1- 2022-01-05T02:24***

***2- 2022-01-05T02:10:58***

I have tried this method:

`dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')`

`df=  pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",",  encoding = "ISO-8859-1", low_memory=False, date_parser=dateparse)`

But it doesn't parse right even this format "2022-01-05T02:10:58"
I want to ask you if there is an alternative to use to parse correctly my columns of type DateTime.

I am using the low_memory= False because when I don't use it, I have this warning:

`DtypeWarning: Columns (28,29,56,71) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False`

Thank you,

Comment: This question probably has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66979036/1328439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas has a very powerful method `pandas.to_datetime()`

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date_string': ['2022-01-05T02:24', '2022-01-05T02:10:58'],
    'value': [12, 17]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_string'])
```

would result in the following dataframe:

```
    date_string           value     date
0   2022-01-05T02:24      12        2022-01-05 02:24:00
1   2022-01-05T02:10:58   17        2022-01-05 02:10:58
```

You can check that the `date` column has been parsed correctly by verifying the datatype of the `df['date']` Series:

```
0   2022-01-05 02:24:00
1   2022-01-05 02:10:58
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: thank you, it was easier to use. i have made adjustments to cover all my columns: 

def convert_to_datetime(df): 
    for col in df.filter(regex='date',axis=1).columns: 
        df[col]= pd.to_datetime(df[col], errors='coerce')
    return df